# How to play private domain Vimeo video in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, vimeo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am trying to call this API using the Bearer authorization token to get video detail.
but still, the video does not play.

```
GET: https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{videoId}
```

Comment: Did you find out how to access the private videos on Vimeo?